# `button_tag` instead of `submit_tag`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to include a glyphicon in my form submit button. It isn't possible to include glyphicons inside `submit_tag`, so I used `button_tag`.

However, in some forms I have different submit_buttons (like `preview`|`for_real`), and I used the:

```
button "commit"
```

message in the controller to have a specific action:

```
if params[:commit] == 'Preview'
```

which only works with `submit_tag`.

#### 1. I'd like to understand the difference between the two.

Rails `submit_tag`

```
submit_tag "Edit this article"
# => <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Edit this article" />
```

and `button_for`

```
<%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-default") do %>
    Edit this article <i class="icon-repeat"></i>
<% end %>
```

Is the difference just that the `input` will also submit a commit message that does not allow HTML/glyphicons?

#### 2. What is the workaround to have a `submit_tag` behavior (commit message) with a glyphicon inside?

Or is it not recommended to use the `commit` value, and something else should be used that would work with `button_tag`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is that there is actually no problem with the `button_tag` solution. Therefore `submit_tag` is just useless (until I find some other advantages it has over button_tag).

```
button_tag(name: 'commit', type: 'submit', value: 'Edit this article')
button_tag(name: 'commit', type: 'submit', value: 'Publish')
```

Although those are both rendered as `<button>` in the HTML, only the value of the one that was clicked will be passsed !